# Create multiple links to websites in main menu of Google Sheets

Tags: if-statement, google-apps-script, hyperlink, conditional-statements, clickable

Well, thanks in advance for those who will help me to solve this one.
What I am trying to do is to create clickable itens in the main menu of Google Sheets. The step of creating multiple drop list items is already overcome, using this script to create menu itens:

```
const onOpen = () => {
  const ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();

  const parentMenu = ui.createMenu('Partners');
  
  parentMenu.addItem('Thebest50s','openWebsite');
  parentMenu.addItem('The20best','openWebsite');
  parentMenu.addToUi();
};
```

Used this HTML as a reference:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <a href="<?= url; ?>" target="_blank">Click here</a> to open the webpage.
  </body>
  <script>
    var windowReference = window.open('<?= url; ?>', '_blank');
    if (windowReference !== null) {
      google.script.host.close();
    }
  </script>
</html>
```

And this script to open the first item of the menu when the client click in it:

```
const openWebsite = () => {
  const htmlTemplate = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('url.html');
  htmlTemplate.url = 'https://www.theworlds50best.com/list/1-50';
  const htmlOutput = htmlTemplate.evaluate().setHeight(50).setWidth(200);
  const ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  ui.showModelessDialog(htmlOutput, 'Thebest50s');
  Utilities.sleep(2000)
```

But obviously I didn't open the second item when I click in it.

I try to put some conditions, but it didn't help. Could someone help to solve this: when click in The20best items it opens https://www.getbento.com/blog/best-restaurant-websites-design/

Answer (score 0):

Try using this script:

```
function onOpen() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createMenu("Partners")
    .addItem("Thebest50s", "openBest50")
    .addItem("The20best", "openBest20")
    .addToUi();
}
 
/**
* Run when "Thebest50s" is selected from the "Partners" menu is clicked.
*
*/
function openBest50(){
  openUrl("https://www.theworlds50best.com/list/1-50'")
};
 
 
/**
* Run when "The20best" is run from the "Partners" menu or when the red YouTube button is clicked.
*/
function openBest20(){
  openUrl("https://www.getbento.com/blog/best-restaurant-websites-design/")
}
 

function openUrl(url){
 
const blob = `
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ssl.gstatic.com/docs/script/css/add-ons1.css">
  </head>
  
  <body>
  <div id="blocked" hidden>
    <p><a href="${url}"onclick="window.open(this.href)" rel="nofollow noopener">Go to link! \>\></a></p>
    <p>You may have popups blocked for Google Workspace.</p>
    <p>You can always remove the popup block for next time. </p>
    <button onclick="google.script.host.close()">Close</button>
  </div>
 
    <script>
      
      const urlLinked = window.open("${url}");
      if(urlLinked){
        google.script.host.close()
      }else{
        document.getElementById("blocked").hidden = false;
      }
    
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
`
 
  const html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(blob)
    .setWidth(400)
    .setHeight(200);
 
const ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  
   ui.showModalDialog(html,"Link")
};
```

This script should show create a custom menu with 2 different options: `TheBest50s` and `The20Best`. You may want to update the menu information as you desire. The problem with your previous script is that you never set the URL for `The20Best` therefore clicking on it will not redirect the user anywhere.